Issue with dynamic IN clause
I have a list of available car models stored in a database field (don't ask..) and I need to use this list in my query's IN clause:
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE model IN (SELECT field1 FROM config_table)

The above returns 0 results. If I replace my subquery with list of actual values it works fine:
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE model IN('Model3', 'C300', 'Civic')

I have tried storing models in various formats but nothing works.
'Model3', 'C300', 'Civic'

"Model3", "C300", "Civic"

Model3,C300,Civic

Any insight?

Can you show a table (text format please) of what (SELECT field1 FROM config_table) looks like? If field one is not one single element per row then it will not work. For instance, if model in table1 is "Civic" and field1 in config_table is "Model3,C300,Civic" (in a single row) these are different strings, hence you not getting any row "Civic" != "Model3,C300,Civic" IN operator compares string to string it is not a contains operation.

The format is Model3,C300,Civic

There is just one row in the config_table? One way to solve this is to create rows with single values from this table in a recursive query. Another is to use string operations to find a substring in a string.

Are you doing this in SQL, PL/SQL, or some other language?  If you're trying to work around a broken data model, this is a very occasional query where the data is not entered by humans and thus subject to SQL injection, and you are using PL/SQL or some other language where you can build a query, you could use dynamic SQL.  More than likely, though, you'd need to parse the CSV data and use the result in your IN clause.  If you have APEX installed, my preference would be to use the apex_util.comma_to_table function but you could write your own.

You can try the below
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE model IN
(
select regexp_substr(field1, '[^,]+',1,level)
from config_table
connect by level <=regexp_count(field1, '[^,]+'));


this format should do Model3,C300,Civic

One of the options  is to extract models with CTE (comments in code)
WITH     -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    config_table AS
        ( Select 'Model3,C300,Civic' "FIELD1" From Dual ),
    
    -- CTE WITH THE MODELS FROM ABOVE
    -- using LEVEL Connect By
    config_models AS    
        ( Select      LEVEL "ID",
                      SubStr(',' || FIELD1 || ',',   -- added commas before and after your FIELD1
                             InStr(',' || FIELD1 || ',', ',', 1, LEVEL + 0) + 1,   -- get starting position
                             InStr(',' || FIELD1 || ',', ',', 1, LEVEL + 1) - InStr(',' || FIELD1 || ',', ',', 1, LEVEL + 0) - 1 ) "MODEL_NAME"  -- length is end position - start position - 1
          From        config_table
          Connect By  LEVEL <= Length(FIELD1) - Length(Replace(FIELD1, ',', '')) + 1  -- number of elements
        ),

/*  R e s u l t :   (config_models)
        ID MODEL_NAME         
---------- -------------------
         1 Model3             
         2 C300               
         3 Civic              */

    table1 AS    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
        ( Select 101 "ID", 1 "MAKER_ID", 'Ka' "MODEL_NAME" From Dual Union All
          Select 102 "ID", 1 "MAKER_ID", 'Focus' "MODEL_NAME" From Dual Union All
          Select 103 "ID", 2 "MAKER_ID", 'Clio' "MODEL_NAME" From Dual Union All
          Select 104 "ID", 2 "MAKER_ID", 'Laguna' "MODEL_NAME" From Dual Union All
          Select 105 "ID", 3 "MAKER_ID", 'Civic' "MODEL_NAME" From Dual
        )

--    S Q L 1 :
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE MODEL_NAME IN (SELECT MODEL_NAME FROM config_models)

OR
--    S Q L 2 :
SELECT      t1.* 
FROM        Table1 t1
INNER JOIN  config_models m ON(m.MODEL_NAME = t1.MODEL_NAME)

...  results the same:
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID   MAKER_ID MODEL_NAME
---------- ---------- ----------
       105          3 Civic       */

